# Write 2 bytes of data, one byte and one byte in reverse by golang

Tags: go, cgo

I have to use a specific C library by Golang and its API in C is

```
int write(unsigned short usCount, unsigned short usData[]);
```

Cannot use like following because its not support indexing for ushort

```
data := make([]C.ushort, 4)

// transfer string to ascii by char and save it to data
data[0][1] = int(char)
data[0][0] = int(char)
data[1][1] = int(char)
data[1][0] = int(char)
...etc

write(4, data);
```

Is any other good operations for this case?

P.S. The indexing is reverse is because I am sending a little endian data.

Comment: Do you encounter a similar error mentioned here or sth else: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13129

Comment: What would be wrong with replacing the idexing to bytes with arithmetic like `(78>>8) + 77` (or the other way around :-)).

Comment: @Volker I guess you mean endianness by "the other way round", but the shift also needs to be the other way round  `<<` not `>>`

Comment: @vahdet, no, the current operation is invalid. Different with above link